# Android; Confused by views?

Tags: android, view, extend

I have created a class (InputControl) which extends the view of my main class (Main), and takes focus of the screen. I have a button on the main xml layout which calls control() and sets up my InputControl view, from there I capture user input.

How can I return back to the xml layout from the InputControl view class?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InputControl = new InputControl(this);
}

//......SNIP!

public void control(){
setContentView(InputControl);
    InputControl.requestFocus();
}

}


public class InputControl extends View implements OnTouchListener {

public InputControl(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

}


public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

//...I AM CAPTURING USER TOUCH EVENTS HERE

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have have a specific reason for doing things this way, a better way might be to have a second activity (InputControlActivity for example) with its own layout file and embed your InputControl class into that.

You would then start an instance of the second activity (with startActivity()) - once you're finished in the InputControlActivity, simply pressing the phone's BACK button will close that activity and return to the main one.

Comment: Hi, this as mostly solved the problem. I did actually have it set up this way before but it didn't work and I couldn't work out why but you have prompted me to go back and try again and I have sorted it, almost ;)

Comment: I have "setFocusableInTouchMode(true);" on my InputControl class so I can capture all key events, I capture touching the screen but also I want to use the volume keys. Because I am capturing system keys like the volume keys, when I press the Back button, I don't close the activity and return to the main one unless I take that line out (presumable because my class is intercepting the event) but then I can't capture volume key presses, is there any way around this?

Comment: @javano: If you are capturing the Back button then you will need to check for when it is pressed. Ideally you should pass it on to the normal key event handler (super) which will process it properley. Alternatively, calling finish() will terminate the activity in the same way the Back button would normally do but only use finish() if you really have to.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up. Where capturing key events under "public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {...}" I have returned false if the button is pressed is the Back button which works just fine. Thanks for the guidance :)